# ReactJS nested data structuring

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm very new to ReactJS as I'm sure is about to be highlighted :-) ... I'm loving it so far but still trying to get my head around a lot of things

Here's what I'm trying to achieve - a list of data with nested lists inside them;

**TV Show - Simpsons**

- Name: Bart Simpson, Gender: Male
- Name: Homer Simpson, Gender: Male
- Name: Ned Flanders, Gender: Male

**TV Show - Flintstones**

- Name: Fred Flintstone, Gender: Male
- Name: Barney Rubble, Gender: Male
- Name: Wilma Flintstone, Gender: Female

etc ...

I've seen that commonly in React that you'll create one element to do one task which I love - but what should you it comes to nested data as I'm trying to achieve above?

I could potentially be trying to do this hundreds of times so I don't want to just create these two lists as React elements of their own

The two ways I can think to achieve this sort of thing would be to either have nested data which would work great for what I'm after but not sure if it is valid / good practice ... something like this

```
var shows = [
    { id: 1, show: 'Simpsons',
    var characters = [
            { id: 1, name: 'Bart Simpson', gender: 'Male'},
            { id: 2, name: 'Homer Simpson', gender: 'Male'},
            { id: 3, name: 'Ned Flanders', gender: 'Male'},
    },
    { id: 2, show: 'Flintstones',
            { id: 1, name: 'Fred Flintstone', gender: 'Male'},
            { id: 2, name: 'Barney Rubble', gender: 'Male'},
            { id: 3, name: 'Wilma Flintstone', gender: 'Female'}, 
    },
];
```

Or maybe grouped data and then somehow build tables from their show types and list the rest of the data as child data ...

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, show: 'Simpsons', name: 'Bart Simpson', gender: 'Male' },
    { id: 2, show: 'Simpsons', name: 'Homer Simpson', gender: 'Male' },
    { id: 3, show: 'Simpsons', name: 'Ned Flanders', gender: 'Male' },
    { id: 4, show: 'Flintstones', name: 'Fred Flintstone', gender: 'Male' },
    { id: 5, show: 'Flintstones', name: 'Barney Rubble', gender: 'Male' },
    { id: 6, show: 'Flintstones', name: 'Wilma Flintstone', gender: 'Female' },
];
```

Seems to be a pretty simple question but I haven't yet found any information on how this would be achieved with React.

If anyone can point me to some information or shed some light on this for me that would be fabulous :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first approach is the better one, although the structure is not correct. To work properly it should be shaped something like this:

```
var shows = [
  {
    id: 1,
    show: 'Simpsons',
    characters: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Bart Simpson', gender: 'Male'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Homer Simpson', gender: 'Male'},
      { id: 3, name: 'Ned Flanders', gender: 'Male'}
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    show: 'Flintstones',
    characters: [
      { id: 1, name: 'Fred Flintstone', gender: 'Male'},
      { id: 2, name: 'Barney Rubble', gender: 'Male'},
      { id: 3, name: 'Wilma Flintstone', gender: 'Female'}
    ]
  }
];
```

Now you can have a `Show` component, something like this:

```
...
import Character from '../Character';

const Show = ({ id, show, characters }) => (
   <div>
     <h1>{show}</h1>
     <ul>
       {
         characters.map(character => (
           <Character
             key={character.id}
             name={character.name}
             gender={character.gender}
           />
         ))
       }
     </ul>
   </div>
 );

 export default Show;
 ...
```

Now you need a `Character` component:

```
...
const Character = ({ name, gender }) => (
   <li><p>{name} | {gender}</p></li>
);

export default Character;
...
```

I feel like this is a very common pattern that I use frequently, now you can use the `Show` component wherever you want in your app. Just make sure that the right props are passed down to it. If you need more clarification let me know!

Comment: Hey G4bri3l - This looks great, I was hoping that the first solution would be the right way of going this, I'm having problems with the 'characters' array at the moment which seems to say there is a syntax error ... are you sure that's the right syntax? I'll have a fiddle with this and see if I can get it to work

Comment: Hey G4bri3l - think I figured the syntax error - it's a : after the 'characters' not an '='

Comment: I got this working G4bri3l - once I fixed the syntax the first option worked great! :-)